# Only sum column values from qualifying rows of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, filtering

I'm used to analysing data in R and have a hard time figuring out array in PHP.

Given the following array (`$dat`), what is the easiest way to get the total number of all females?

```
print("<pre>".print_r($dat,true)."</pre>");

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => female
            [1] => blue
            [2] => 62
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => female
            [1] => red
            [2] => 22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => male
            [1] => blue
            [2] => 21
        )

)
```

I'm doing this:

```
foreach($dat as $row) {
    if($row[0]=='female') {
        $females = $females + $row[2];
    }
}
```

But there must be a way without loops!

Isn't there something like `sum($dat[][2])`?

---

## Result for this sample should be 84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `array_reduce` your array to a sum that way :

```
$array[0] = array('female', 2);
$array[1] = array('female', 5);
$array[2] = array('male', 2);

$sum = array_reduce($array, function ($value, $item) {
    if ($item[0] == 'female') $value += $item[1];
    return $value;
}, 0);

var_dump($sum);
```

Output :

```
7
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems I misinterpreted your question...

To obtain the sum, you can use `array_reduce` instead of a `foreach` loop (although it's not going to be much of an improvement):

```
array_reduce($dat, function($prev,$curr){return $prev+($curr[0]==='female'?$curr[2]:0);}, 0);
```

---

To obtain the number of elements containing 'female', You could use `count` with `array_filter`:

```
echo count(array_filter($dat, function($x){return in_array('female', $x);}));
```

This filters the array for any sub-arrays that contain the string `female` and returns the number of elements.

If you're sure that the string `'female'` is always the zeroth element of the array, you could simplify the function slightly:

```
echo count(array_filter($dat, function($x){return $x[0]==='female';}));
```

Comment: Well, this guy deserves a cookie. +1

Comment: Yes, but you still can do something else inside the function, I personally liked the idea of using array_filter instead of the foreach. @ClémentMalet